# c# finding a string in a text file then do something?

Tags: c#

ok what im trying to do here is the following

```
       private void addgsc()
    {
        if (File.Exists(hud))
        {
            {
                string s = "    itemDef\n\r"
+ "{"
+ " name \"zombiecounter\"\n\r"
+ " rect         100 70 0 0 HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER VERTICAL_ALIGN_BOTTOM\n\r "
+ " textscale      .5\n\r"
+ " textstyle      ITEM_TEXTSTYLE_SHADOWED\n\r"
+ " textfont      UI_FONT_OBJECTIVE\n\r"
+ " textalign      ITEM_ALIGN_CENTER\n\r"
+ " forecolor      1 0 0 1\n\r"
+ " exp text      (\"Zombies Left: \" + dvarInt(\"zombie_counter\"))\n\r"
+ "  visible   when    (dvarInt(\"zombie_counter\") > 0);\n\r"
+ "decoration\n\r"
+ "}   ";

                string file = hud;
                List<string> lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file));
                int index = lines.FindLastIndex(item => item.Contains("playerscores"));
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    lines.Insert(index + 1, s);//""
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
                MessageBox.Show("done");
            }

        }
```

and im looking for a line in a code like this

```
     itemDef
   {
      name         "playerscores"
      rect         0 0 100 0
      ownerdraw      CG_COMPETITIVE_MODE_SCORES
      visible         1
   }
```

but what i want to do is find player scores then find the last } at the end and add it there because currently its adding it right under player scores but im not sure how i can get it to go to find that and then find the closest } one of those and add it under neath that so its in a new block not added into the player score one so would want something like the following

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAP7.png)

Comment: Do you prefer regex, or will simple IndexOf() be sufficient?

Comment: simple indexof() would be perfectly fine its just i never had to do something like this before so little unclear on what the best method is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear of the desired output, so the below code may be more than what you need but should get you on the right track. Please forgive syntax errors.

EDIT: I reread the question a few times, and think this is what you are looking for.

```
var allLinesInFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
var isPlayerScore = false;
var linesToWrite = new List<string>();
var linesToAdd = new List<string> {
  "itemDef\n\r",
  "{",
  " name \"zombiecounter\"\n\r",
  //and so on
  "}"
};

foreach (var line in allLinesInFile)
{
  linesToWrite.Add(line);

  if (line.IndexOf("playerscores", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
  { 
     //starting of data detected. 
     isPlayerScore = true;
  }
  else if (isPlayerScore == true && line.IndexOf("}") >= 0)
  {
     //end of data detected
     isPlayerScore = false;
     linesToWrite.AddRange(linesToAdd);
  }
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, linesToWrite);
MessageBox.Show("done");
```

Comment: thank you for you reply :) only issue im having is this  http://i.imgur.com/NKVkVMZ.png

Comment: was missing >= 0 in the second indexof.